# NSSegmentedCell subclass drawing

Tags: cocoa, subclass, nssegmentedcontrol

I have created subclass of NSSegmentedCell and implemented drawWithFrame as following:

```
#import "CustomSegmentedCell.h"

@implementation CustomSegmentedCell

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    int i=0, count=[self segmentCount];
    NSRect segmentFrame=cellFrame;

    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        segmentFrame.size.width=[self widthForSegment:i];
        [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
        // Make sure that segment drawing is not allowed to spill out into other segments
        NSBezierPath* clipPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: segmentFrame];
        [clipPath addClip];
        [self drawSegment:i inFrame:segmentFrame withView:controlView];
        [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
        segmentFrame.origin.x+=segmentFrame.size.width;
    }

    _lastDrawRect=cellFrame;

}

@end
```

The problem is segments didn't get drawn on first launch of app, it gets visible only when i clicked with mouse on blank area where segmented Control suppose to drawn.Please let me know, what i am missing here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Subclass and implement `drawSegment:inFrame:withView:`

```
- (void)drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)frame withView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame xRadius:8 yRadius:8];
    [path setClip];
    [path setLineWidth:2.5];
    [[NSColor grayColor] setStroke];
    NSColor* bgColr;
    if (segment%2) {
        bgColr = [NSColor blackColor];
    }
    else {
        bgColr = [NSColor redColor];
    }

    [bgColr setFill];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:frame];  

}
```

Comment: Thanks Parag for the code, the requirement was quite old, but i appreciate your help.

Comment: I note that the frame passed as an argument is sometimes too small and only a center piece of the cell is filled. Any idea what is going on here?